# Is there a XML parser that allows mismatched tags?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-parsing, lxml

I'm trying to find an XML parser that allows me to take control of building the document tree and to fix mismatched tags myself. For example, I want to be able to fix the following in my code

```
<item>
    <name>The name
    <value>A value</value>
</item>
```

lxml allows me to take control of building the tree using the target parameter of the XMLParser but it keeps an internal track of open tags which I can't manually close so it'll throw an error on invalid XML. To automatically fix XML I can use the recover parameter but there's no way to define how it fixes problems. This is an issue because it often makes the wrong decision.

I've had similar problems trying to use built-in libraries such as expat, ElementTree and sax. I know what I'm trying to parse isn't technically XML but I would like a way to programmatically turn it into valid XML without writing a completely new parser myself.

Comment: Most of the parsers built to try to reconstruct mangled DOMs into something sensible target HTML rather than XML. Even then, though, you're unlikely to get detailed control as to how issues are resolved.

Comment: I'd almost lean towards using the recover flag as it is, and trying to recognize and fix up the mangled DOM elements that leaves.

Comment: @Charles I was hoping to avoid that but you're right that it may well be my best option.

Comment: Rather than ad-hoc patches, check the processing of original source XML creation as app/script is not producing well-formed XML files. Possibly script writes custom text file to be used as xml and not one created with a DOM document object (that add elements/children/attributes). Most parsers beyond Python will not accept such files.